# Bash "move files" error message

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to move some files based on a search pattern using bash but I get an error message. Here is the borrowed script format I used and the error message. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

firstdir=dir1
seconddir=dir2


for i in 'grep -l matchpattern $firstdir/*'; do
    mv $i $seconddir
    echo $i
done
```

error message:

```
mv: invalid option -- 'l'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
grep -l problem $firstdir/*
```

PS I have been looking for quite some time for an answer, but getting nowhere.

Comment: You only can mark one of given answers as your answer. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing scripts, if you have an error, you need to `echo` your variables to understand what is happening. This is the first step in debugging. Had you done so, you would have seen that the `grep` command is not being executed and is instead being saved as `$i`:

```
$ for i in 'grep -l matchpattern $firstdir/*'; do 
    echo "i is: $i"; 
  done
i is: grep -l matchpattern $firstdir/*
```

In order to pass the results of a command, you need to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). That's either `` `command` `` or, better, `$(command)`. So, what you wanted to do was:

```
for i in $(grep -l matchpattern "$firstdir"/*); do 
    mv "$i" "$seconddir"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like I need to change some permissions, but I am uncertain how to do that. I get this message: line 5: Command: command not found
grep: /lost+found: Permission denied
grep: /root: Permission denied
grep: /vmlinuz: Permission denied
grep: /vmlinuz.old: Permission denied

Comment: @David please ask follow-up questions as separate posts. I can't help you with your `line 5:` error because that is caused by something you're not showing in your question. The rest of the errors are because you are, for some reason, searching through `/` and your normal user doesn't have permissions to read all files there. I suggest you post a  new question, showing _your entire script_ and explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ Sylvain Pineau OK, thank you, that was very gracious of you! Have a nice day!

Comment: @KasiyA fair enough. That is still not enough of course, and a better way would be `grep ... | while IFS= read -r i` but never mind... :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the quotes around the `grep` command for [backticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash):

```
for i in `grep -l matchpattern "$firstdir"/*`; do
```

Or adopt the new-style `$()`:

```
for i in $(grep -l matchpattern "$firstdir"/*); do
```

Source: [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778)

Comment: Thank you Sylvain! The command executed without problem the first time around, but when I tried to search for another word, I got this message: line 5: Command: command not found
grep: /lost+found: Permission denied
grep: /root: Permission denied
grep: /vmlinuz: Permission denied
grep: /vmlinuz.old: Permission denied  Can you help with that? Thank you!